# By the time our method is proposed

Tags: grammaticality

I'm writing a scientific paper. In a sentence I'm trying to say that:

> By the time our method is proposed, there seems to be no prior similar
> attempt in which WSN is used.

but according to the reviewers comments, this sentence is not good and needs to be rephrased by a native speaker. I wanted to know what's wrong with this sentence and how I can correct it?

Comment: I suggest "At the time of writing there has been no other attempt to use WSN for this purpose that we know of."

Comment: I think ***by the time*** might be a "positive polarity" construction, in that it's invariably used in contexts where *by the time [something happened], [something else] **had already happened***. As opposed to ***As at** [time of something happening]...*, which would normally be followed by *[something else] **had NOT [yet] happened***.